# App_GlobalResources doesn't work in my web application

Tags: asp.net, app-globalresources

I created two resx files and add them to App_GlobalResources folder under my application.

[image]

here are the values

[image]

[image]

and here my label

[image]

So I changed the language settings in Internet Explorer

[image]

and it's not working. I only can see english version. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does it work when you add `<%@ Page UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>
` at the top of page?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `LocalizedText.es-mx.resx` to `LocalizedText.es-MX.resx`

If that doesn't work then, delete `LocalizedText.resx`, this will let you know if it is a resource file look up issue.

Last resort, make sure your app pool is recycling.

Comment: You meant to say "capitalize the `MX`" part, I believe. The dash before the `es` should actually be a `.`, right?

Comment: It's should be right. I tried it also doesn't make any difference

Comment: Doesn't add up, if you have only one .resx file the MX version and you recycle the App Pool, it is either going to show you the right text or bomb.